# A book of mystery - Page I

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, story

APOLOGIES AS THE FIRST SET OF NUMBERS WAS INCORRECT. THIS IS MY FIRST TIME WRITING A PROPER STORY RIDDLE SO EXCUSE ME IF IT'S NOT GREAT. YOU'LL GET A NEW PAGE OF THE BOOK EACH TIME YOU SOLVE THE LAST ONE. ENJOY!

As he lay on his deathbed, aged at just forty four, 
Your uncle James was holding your mother's hand and yours.
To her, he gave a house, the other 3 were given to his spouse
His mother got the millions held within his bank
and his sister (your aunt) got his shares in oil tanks
But what did you get? He handed you a book
Nothing written in but the first page 'what is it?' but too late
His last breath had been took

You opened the book and the first page read as follows:

> There are many a-book by Rowling, JK
>   The most famous series over a half-billion to this day
>   Take the first book
>   Turn to chapter three
>   And count the nth letters
>   Along with me
>
> 1 2 19 30 34 36 43 56 73 77 88
>   90 114 247 268 300 306 318 320 408
>
> *NOTE: No title*

But what does it mean, I'm really not sure
Please help me figure it, I implore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> 'This code belongs to Sam'

Following the instructions:

> The first book in J.K. Rowling's Harry Potter series is Harry Potter and the philosphers stone. Not including the title and removing all punctuation, the extract for the first few words of chapter three, 'The letters from No One':
>
> 'The escape of the Brazilian boa constrictor earned Harry his longest ever punishment By the time he was allowed out of his cupboard again the summer holidays had started and Dudley had already broken his new cine camera crashed his remote control aeroplane and first time on his racing bike knocked down old Mrs Figg as she crossed Privet Drive on her crutches Harry was glad school was over but there was no escaping Dudleys gang who visited the house every single day Piers Dennis Malcolm and Gordon were all big and stupid but as Dudley was the biggest and stupidest of the lot he was the leader The rest of them were all quite happy to join in Dudleys favourite sport Harry hunting '

But taking the nth letter gives:

> **THIS CODE BELONECASAOD**

@LannyStrack has realised if

> We subtract 10/20 from some numbers and use 237 258 280 286 298 300 388 for the last few numbers we get:
>
> '**THIS CODE BELONGS TO SAP**'

And the last letter should have been an 'M'

Comment: Have you tried including/excluding spaces and punctuation?

Comment: @Stiv yes, with spaces the 3rd letter becomes a space which doesn't make sense with 'TH ' and punctuation doens't change much, as there is pretty little. The instructions say letters and that gives the above string, but not sure what now.

Comment: @Beastly Gerbil I have rewitten it as I made a mistake with the numbers Sorry :)

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I've just gone through the new string. I think there still could be some errors in there

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil this does not include any sort of punctuation

Comment: I have double-checked it and it does work :)

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I'm assuming no spaces? I'll check, I may have accidently removed a character or something

Comment: You've missed an O in the 6th position (you only have 19 letters total whereas the ciphertext is 20) - you may wish to recheck the rest too ;-)

Comment: I think you might also have a UK vs US version issue here - 'airplane' vs 'aeroplane' for one thing...

Comment: @Stiv I'm getting the same results for the version I'm using, so thats probably the case

Comment: @WilliamPennanti what version of the harry potter are you looking at? I'm finding differnet versions online with different wordings

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil englishonlineclub.com

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I've used the version you linked and double checked. This is what I get. After 247 it doesn't make much sense. I've editted the paragraph I'm using into my answer so you can check it.

Comment: rot13/ SJVJ, vs lbh fhogenpg 10 sebz gur 14gu naq 15gu ahzoref, naq 20 sebz gur erfg (v.r., raq jvgu 237 258 280 286 298 300 388), lbh trg "Guvf pbqr orybatf gb Fnc."

Comment: @LannyStrack you got it right there except from ROT13(Gur ynfg yrggre vf na 'z')

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I've updated the answer, but I'm still very confused. Why do we need to subtract numbers and is there a pattern to that? Also the last number doesn't seem to give 'M' in any way, the only nearby ones are 405 and 399

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I'm sorry but I think I've just really messed up the numbers and I don't know how. I'll make sure to be more thorough with the later ones

Comment: @WilliamPennanti don't worry, it can be quite easy to make mistakes, especially when using sources from elsewhere! Still looking forward to the next ones :)